# Create a new farm user

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, configuration, user-accounts, farm

I have a onpremises sharepoint server 2016 and I want to create a new farm user. If I create a new with the sames permissions that the old farm user have is enough to work? Or I have to set up something in sharepoint configurantion?

Comment: Can you define "farm user"? SharePoint Server admin (human), a service account? Some other user account?

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP Is a service account.

Answer (score 0):

What permission you need to give to this new user account is based on what you want to do with it.

If you want to create a new farm account for SharePoint configuration, you need to grant both local rights and domain right to this account, as well as put the user account in the proper group.

If it is just a test account that will not be in significant use, you don’t need to grant permission to this user in AD.

Basically, if you have set up a new SharePoint farm which is the same as the original one, users of the new farm who have the same permission in the original farm won’t be needing additional configuration.

Reference:

[SharePoint Farm User Accounts.](https://mstechtalk.com/sharepoint-farm-user-accounts/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give someone rights to manage the farm(you are looking for someone to manage the farm central administration) , the easiest thing would be to add the user in the Farm administrators group .

Go to Central Administration -> Security -> Manage the Farm Administrator group -> Add the user .

You can call this person as a farm user although not technically but I think this is something you are looking for .

Let me know ..

Answer (score 0):

SP Service Accounts are regular AD accounts with the expection of some special cases like UPS which needs AD sync.  A service account is a service account.  You can assign those in Central Admin to run different services for the farm.  If you are looking for a farm management account, do like [@yash.kamdar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/79228/yash-kamdar) said and do it through Central Admin. Create your service accounts in AD and set them to spacific SP tasks in your farm to do in the back end. The only "farm accounts" that are service accounts should be your SPFarm and SPAdmin accounts.  You should not need a third, or have any way to use them in that same scope of SP roles.